# IPhone application removal from the appstore?

Tags: iphone

I have an application in IPhone which is now on sale.I want to submit an updated version to my application.which is 1.7.Now 1.6 is on sale.Actually i have done all the metadata submission of the version 2.0 for the in-app purchase process.But Now because of a major bugg i need to submit 1.7 soon. How i can remove the metadata of 2.0 that i have already submitted.Any help will be grately appreciated.

Comment: Easiest way is just to delete that version after rejecting the binary and starting again.

Comment: Easiest way is just to delete that version after rejecting the binary and starting again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already submitted the 2.0 binary, you should be able to edit whatever data you've entered in iTunes Connect.